# Wanting a custom import for sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new to sugarcrm and one of the first things I need to do is figure out away to import some custom data to some leads I currently have in the system.  It didn't take much time to realize that it was going to take quite a while to figure this out on my own after looking at the developer information on the site.

The data that I want to import will hope fully be imported and added to a new history item for the particular lead.  We are doing some actions to the leads outside of the crm and I want to batch update the crm data adn store it in the history.

I was thinking that a good place for this might be in the import window for the leads.  Maybe adding another radio selection to the area that says "What would you like to do with the imported data?" and then add processes to handle this type of import.

The other possibility is a new tab for the upload and process it there.

I am currently unsure of the best approach, as I am learning how to add functionality to sugar.

I could really use some guidance on what might be the best way to proceed and maybe some pointers to where I can find more information.

By the way this is the CE version 6.5

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always tools like Talend to look at if you really have custom import requirements, but I'm somewhat wondering what requirements you have that can't be handled by the built in tool? It should be able to import into custom fields fine.

Comment: The problem is my inexperience with sugarcrm.  The data I want to import would contain an id number to a lead but I want to have additional data stored in a new history item for each of the leads in the csv file.  There may be a few history items added over time.  If the standard import would work that would be great I just don't understand enough to know how to do it.

Comment: Sounds like a more advanced tool like Talend makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

I used Sugar in the past and I have to say it's always been a mess. The customer service is really lacking too. To be honest with you, I canceled my account within 2 months.